# How to scale skin modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm currently learning how to sculpt in Blender, and my course instructor has had me make a skin modifier basemesh. Unfortunately, he told me to use the shortcut "ctrl-a" to scale up the thickness of certain vertices/edges of my basemesh—an operation I cannot complete because I assigned (edit mode) ctrl+a to do a different operation.

Is there another way to complete this operation, and if not, how do I get my hotkey back to the default?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another way to complete operation: hit the Space bar, start typing "skin resize"

Change your hotkey: in the User Preferences window, in the "Input" section, you can search for "skin resize" when searching by Name, that will let you assign a new (or old) keyboard shortcut for that operation.

To find what you've got assigned to Ctrl-A, search by Key Binding and type "Ctrl A", that will show everything that's bound to that combination.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the Mean Radius X and Y properties in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) when in Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to adjust the skin radius for the selected vertices. Note that this allows the skin to be scaled in each direction independently.

[image]

Comment: OMF you can skin cages? I've been using wireframe and getting bad results. +1