# Change proportion on base mesh

Tags: bmesh

I discovered a video that shows a very quick way to make base mesh (skin modifier as everyone already knows)

[image]

but it's a timelapse, so there's no explanation at all.

In 01:00 he starts to scale vertex to change proportion for each part of the body.

[image]

[image]

the problem is, I don't know how he did it, because I try to scale vertex but nothing happens I used S and alt S.

The video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFE-NR9623w

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100763/how-to-scale-skin-modifier. The shortcut and behaviour is still the same in default keymap in 2.8

Answer (score 0):

they made the centre point "root" (for skin modifier) in edit mode, then turned on skin again (but in edit mode still), then they selected all and scaled in "median point" I assume, then left edit etc..  I tried it but am not used to mirror in this way :) So could scale but it was a mess.